# Delete rows with value if not only value in group

Tags: r

Somewhat new to R and I find myself needing to delete rows based on multiple criteria. The data frame has 3 columns and I need to delete rows where bid=99 and there are values less than 99 grouping by rid and qid. The desired output at an rid and qid level are bid has multiple values less than 99 or bid=99.

```
  rid  qid  bid
   1    1   5
   1    1   6
   1    1   99
   1    2   6
   2    1   7
   2    1   99
   2    2   2
   2    2   3
   3    1   7
   3    1   8
   3    2   1
   3    2   99
   4    1   2
   4    1   6
   4    2   1
   4    2   2
   4    2   99
   5    1   99
   5    2   99
```

The expected output...

```
  rid  qid bid
   1    1   5
   1    1   6
   1    2   6
   2    1   7
   2    2   2
   2    2   3
   3    1   7
   3    1   8
   3    2   1
   4    1   2
   4    1   6
   4    2   1
   4    2   2
   5    1   99
   5    2   99
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to eliminate where `bid = 99` yet your desired output has rows where `bid=99`?

Comment: @JohnFriel      Only delete bid=99 if there are values less than 99 grouped by rid and qid. Where rid=5, qid=1, bid=99  and again rid=5, qid=2, bid=99 are allowable because there are no other values within the grouping of rid and qid.

Comment: Ok, got it! @Atw67 - I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the base R function `ave` to generate a dropping variable like this:

```
df$dropper <- with(df, ave(bid, rid, qid, FUN= function(i) i == 99 & length(i) > 1))
```

`ave` calculates a function on bid, grouping by rid and qid. The function tests if each element of the grouped bid values i is 99 and if i has a length greater than 1. Also, `with` is used to reduce typing.

which returns

```
df
   rid qid bid dropper
1    1   1   5       0
2    1   1   6       0
3    1   1  99       1
4    1   2   6       0
5    2   1   7       0
6    2   1  99       1
7    2   2   2       0
8    2   2   3       0
9    3   1   7       0
10   3   1   8       0
11   3   2   1       0
12   3   2  99       1
13   4   1   2       0
14   4   1   6       0
15   4   2   1       0
16   4   2   2       0
17   4   2  99       1
18   5   1  99       0
19   5   2  99       0
```

then drop the undesired observations with `df[dropper == 0, 1:3]` which will simultaneously drop the new variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just delete rows where `bid = 99` then use `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

 df <- df %>%
        filter(bid != 99)
```

Where `df` is your data frame. and `!=` means `not equal to`

---

---

Updated solution using `dplyr`

```
df %>%
 group_by(rid, qid) %>%
 mutate(tempcount = n())%>%
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(DropValue =ifelse(bid == 99 & tempcount > 1, 1,0) ) %>%
 filter(DropValue == 0) %>%
select(rid,qid,bid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`, which is a very expressive framework for this kind of problems.

```
df <- read.table(text =
"  rid  qid  bid
   1    1   5
   1    1   6
   1    1   99
   1    2   6
   2    1   7
   2    1   99
   2    2   2
   2    2   3
   3    1   7
   3    1   8
   3    2   1
   3    2   99
   4    1   2
   4    1   6
   4    2   1
   4    2   2
   4    2   99
   5    1   99
   5    2   99",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Dplyr verbs allow to express the program in a way that is close to the very terms of your questions:

```
library(dplyr)
res <-
  df %>% 
  group_by(rid, qid) %>% 
  filter(!(any(bid < 99) & bid == 99)) %>% 
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 15 × 3
#      rid   qid   bid
#    <int> <int> <int>
# 1      1     1     5
# 2      1     1     6
# 3      1     2     6
# 4      2     1     7
# 5      2     2     2
# 6      2     2     3
# 7      3     1     7
# 8      3     1     8
# 9      3     2     1
# 10     4     1     2
# 11     4     1     6
# 12     4     2     1
# 13     4     2     2
# 14     5     1    99
# 15     5     2    99
```

Let's check we get the desired output:

```
desired_output <- read.table(text =
"  rid  qid bid
   1    1   5
   1    1   6
   1    2   6
   2    1   7
   2    2   2
   2    2   3
   3    1   7
   3    1   8
   3    2   1
   4    1   2
   4    1   6
   4    2   1
   4    2   2
   5    1   99
   5    2   99",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
identical(as.data.frame(res), desired_output)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `all` and `if` condition in `data.table` to subset the rows after grouping by 'rid' and 'qid'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(all(bid==99)) .SD else .SD[bid!= 99], .(rid, qid)]
#     rid qid bid
# 1:   1   1   5
# 2:   1   1   6
# 3:   1   2   6
# 4:   2   1   7
# 5:   2   2   2
# 6:   2   2   3
# 7:   3   1   7
# 8:   3   1   8
# 9:   3   2   1
#10:   4   1   2
#11:   4   1   6
#12:   4   2   1
#13:   4   2   2
#14:   5   1  99
#15:   5   2  99
```

---

Or without using the `if`

```
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[all(bid==99) |  bid != 99], .(rid, qid)]$V1]
```